# powershell: get-psdrive and where-object

Tags: windows, powershell, logic

Im trying to find every drive letter that isnt "C,E,L,S,T,W" on a windows 2008 server.  Can anyone tell me the fault in my logic or how i can do this please?

```
[char[]]”CELSTW” | Where-Object {!(Get-PSDrive $_ )}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are starting out with a list of drive letters you don't want (CELSTW) and outputting the ones that don't exist as a psdrive.

What you want is to start with a list of all PSDrives and filter them out where they match the ones you don't want:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object { [char[]]"CELSTW" -notcontains $_.Name }
```

Although that is going to give you a bunch of other PSDrive types.  You probably also want to filter it for the FileSystem provider:

```
 Get-PSDrive | Where-Object { [char[]]"CELSTW" -notcontains $_.Name -AND $_.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you all psdrives where the name (driveletter) isn't "C,E,L,S,T,W"

```
Get-PSDrive  | ?{[char[]]"CELSTW" -notcontains $_.name}
```

however if you want to exclude non-filesystem psdrives, try this:

```
Get-PSDrive  | ?{[char[]]"CELSTW" -notcontains $_.name} | ?{$_.Provider.name -eq "FileSystem"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must go for this from the other end:

```
$drives = [char[]]"CD"
Get-PSDrive | ? { $drives -notcontains $_.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using the -notmatch operator:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch '[CELSTW]'}
```

Comment: This would exclude PSDrives like `CEL` too. I wouldn't necessarily assume what people name their PSDrives (although I kept it sane by only creating `Home`).

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I updated the regex pattern to a "character set" to allow only one match out of several characters.

Comment: You changed the string to match, but not the regex ;)

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Funny, I get the same result both ways.

Comment: I promise, one day I'll stop pestering you, but you started with the regex route :P ... This changes the semantics to excluding any drive name *containing* one of the letters, which, once again, is not exactly what they want (which would be excluding the drives C, E, L, S, T and W). I know, what I'm debating here is highly theoretical and depends on unusual configurations but it *can* happen :)